# Where to find the shared folder in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, vmware, shared-folders

I use *Kali Linux* as a virtual machine in *VMware Workstation Player* with *Windows 10 Home* as host.
The *Player* has the option to pick a *Windows* folder to be used as a shared folder.
I set this up, it says it's enabled, but in *Kali Linux* this shared folder should be present in `/mnt/hgfs`. `/mnt` exists, but is empty. I'm stuck here.

Comment: You need to learn that on Unix/BSD/Linux, they are "directories" and not the Windows-ism of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Comment: Conceptually they are the same to me. The details is in the semantics.

Comment: If you are going to run Linux, use the correct terminology. [They are not the same thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078845/162698)

Answer (score 7):

Both *stackprotector's* AND *petoetje59's* answer helped with this issue.

1. `cd /mnt/hgfs`
2. **If the folder is missing** --> `sudo mkdir hgfs`
3. `sudo vim /etc/fstab`
4. Enter `vmhgfs-fuse /mnt/hgfs fuse defaults,allow_other,nofail 0 0` at the end of the file and save
5. `sudo reboot now`
6. `ls /mnt/hgfs`
7. The Shared Folder you enabled in VMware Fusion Settings will appear

Answer (score 0):

The short of it is below, but here's a little [ten minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUDup4RibEs) that goes through a good step by step process.

Even if the hgfs folder was present, it would be empty. The host has made the files available to the vm, but the vm still needs to be told about their presence. The same thing happens occasionally when you plug in a thumb drive. To do this, from the Kali command line you use the mount command. After you're done working with the shared folder I would use umount, so that I wouldn't have a persistent connection across my operating systems. Keep us updated on your fix.

Answer (score 0):

Executed the instructions mentioned in that video, and as expected, that guy on *Youtube* left out half the story to make it really work - even by reading up on the comments... Sigh.
I finally assembled everything I found into my answer, and tested it successfully.

I have a working *VMware Workstation Player* (VMWP) with *Windows 10 Home* as the host and *Kali Linux 2020.2* as guest OS. The required *VMware Tools for Linux* have been installed (I use a premade VM image which had them already embedded).

To REALLY setup a shared folder for both OS:

1. Create the shared folder on the host, e.g.: `E:\VM_SHARE`
2. Start the guest.
3. From the VMWP :

> ```
> Player
> Manage
> Virtual Machine Settings...
> Options tab
> Shared Folders
> Always enabled
> Add..., Next
> Browse...
> Host path : E:\VM_SHARE
> Name : VM_SHARE
> Next
> Enable this share
> Finish
> OK
> ```

4. According to [this](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_sharedfolder_viewing.html) the shared folder on the guest is supposed to appear in `/mnt/hgfs` but the last folder was missing on my system. Open a terminal window in the guest, and create the missing folder:

> ```
> cd /mnt
> sudo mkdir hgfs
> ```

5. From the terminal window create (or add to) the - in my case also missing - file `/etc/rc.local`:

> ```
> mousepad /etc/rc.local
> ```

Add the following line:

> ```
> sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other
> ```

Important, the first line in this file has to be: `#!/bin/sh -e`

Save the file.

6. No you're not there yet, the file must be made executable:

> ```
> ls -l /etc/rc.local
> ```

In my case this line started with the wrong attributes: `-rw-r--r--`

Make it executable:

> ```
>    sudo chown root /etc/rc.local
>    sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
> ```

Test : `ls -l /etc/rc.local`

The right attributes should now be: `-rwxr-xr-x`

7. Put some test file `test.txt` in `E:\VM_SHARE` on the host.
8. Restart the VM, and check whether the test file also appears on the guest - using the graphical *File System* on the guest's desktop:

> `/mnt/hgfs/VM_SHARE/test.txt`

That's it.

If I missed something that might also spoil things, feel free to add to this answer.

Comment: For people finding this answer in the future, most of what your answer is dong is getting the folder to mount itself on bootup by editing the rc files. This is unnecessarily complicated. The line "sudo mount -t fuse.vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o allow_other" is where all of the magic happens. Because it's a complicated command, I recommend to the average user to make it an alias that you can either run yourself, or put into ~.bashrc which will run when you launch your shell, effectively auto-mounting it. In general, you shouldn't mess with rc files in /etc. Glad it works for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to your `/etc/fstab` and reboot your machine:

```
vmhgfs-fuse /mnt/hgfs fuse defaults,allow_other 0 0
```

You will find your shared folder at `/mnt/hgfs/<FOLDER_NAME>` afterwards.